# How to merge more than one image into one image using php CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

What I am trying to do is something like the following (Final result 1 image):

[image: Final result]

8 images turned into one single image with a background image. Now I know that CI supports GD, GD2, ImageMagick, NetPBM but the current functionality implemented in CI for image manipulation can't do something like this. is there a better CI_Image_lib that I can use to do this or **extends** and do what I am looking for.

background image:
[image: background image]

Finally it will look like this:
[image: Finally image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally managed to do it using the **CodeIgniter** - **Image manipulation class** - **watermark**. I used the watermark as the 8 images I want to merge to each other like so:

```
<?php

class Merge_image extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $config = array(
            'source_image' => 'assets/images/tv-share.jpg',//background image
            'new_image' => 'assets/public/images/tv-share-done.jpg',
            'wm_overlay_path' => 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png',//image number 1
            'wm_vrt_offset' => '180',
            'wm_hor_offset' => '50',
        );
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png';//image number 2
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174646.png';//image number 3
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png';//image number 4
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = $config['wm_vrt_offset'] + 180;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = 50;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174646.png';//image number 5
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png';//image number 6
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174646.png';//image number 7
        $data = $this->watermark($config);

        $config = $data;
        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = $config['wm_hor_offset'] + 180;
        $config['source_image'] = $data['new_image'];
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png';//image number 8
        $data = $this->watermark($config);
        $this->load->view('merge_image_view', $data);
    }

    private function watermark($config) {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
//        $config['source_image'] = 'assets/images/tv-share.jpg';
//        $config['new_image'] = 'assets/public/images/tv-share-done.jpg';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
//        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/public/images/1401174641.png';
        $config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
//        $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '180';
//        $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '50';
//        $config['dynamic_output'] = TRUE;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            die();
        }
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        return $config;
    }

}
```

of course I am going to do it as a loop and not copy and past, this is just to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can do this with:

```
convert +append image1 image2 image3 image4 row1.jpg
convert +append image5 image6 image7 image8 row2.jpg
convert -append row1.jpg row2.jpg combined.jpg
composite -resize "1x1<" -gravity center combined.jpg background.jpg montage.jpg
```

or in one step using

```
montage
```

but you need to be cleverer than me to work out parameters!